# Difference between .at<uchar> and static_cast<uchar> in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a float matrix a and I want to access the element at the point (x,y), but I want to convert the data type to unsigned char. The float number in point(x,y) is 652.759

The code I want to use (which is based on Opencv)is

```
    a.at<uchar>(Point(x,y))
```

The result of above code is 68.

But when I checked the result with simple c++ code

```
    static_cast<unsigned char>(a.at<float>(Point(x,y)))
```

the result is 140.

Anyone knows why? How can I get the same results by using both the code above?

Thx!

Comment: What does this `at` function look like?

Comment: @BaummitAugen  "at" is a build-in function in opencv. It is just used to get the element at one point. But I do not know how the opencv source code convert the data type......

Answer (score 2):

The `at()` function is agnostic as to the number of bits per point, and bases its judgement on the supplied template type.

So, `at<float>(2)` will return a float composed of a 32 bits range starting from the 4th byte of the array, while `at<uchar>(2)` will simply return the second byte in the array.

For example, the following

```
Mat m(10, 1, CV_8U);

m.at<uchar>(0) = 44;
m.at<uchar>(1) = 1;
m.at<uchar>(2) = 0;
m.at<uchar>(3) = 0;

cout << "char 0  : " << (int)m.at<uchar>(0) << endl;
cout << "char 1  : " << (int)m.at<uchar>(1) << endl;
cout << "short 0 : " << (int)m.at<unsigned short>(0) << endl;
```

produces

```
char 0  : 44
char 1  : 1
short 0 : 300
```

`short 0` = `char 1` * `256` + `char 0`

Comment: It makes more sense! Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello! Do you know how opencv uses .at<> to convert a Vec3f variable to uchar? For example, I have a floating-point image pixel and I want to use at<uchar> to access it. How opencv achieves it?

Comment: as stated in my answer, the `at` function is agnostic to the `datatype` of your `Mat`. You'll have to call `at<Vec3f>(...)` and then convert that Vec3f to a uchar yourself. As a rule of thumb, always use the same type for both the template type for `at` function and for the `Mat::datatype`. Be aware that Vec3f is normally normalised to be between 0 and 1, while uchar is obviously between 0 and 255. So, you'll need to do your own maths... for example `uchar x1 = uchar(myVec3f[0] * 255f)`

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same difference than in this code:

```
float f = 140.f;
unsigned char c = static_cast<unsigned char>(f); // c is 140, this is ok
unsigned char wrong = *((unsigned char*)&f); // this is wrong
```

The last line is the same as the `a.at<uchar>(Point(x,y))` you have in your code. This is wrong because it access a `float` and reinterprets it (its bytes) as an `unsigned char`. There is no actual conversion of the binary values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I plug in the number 652.759 into the wrong code you provided, I got 147 instead of 68.....in fact, 68 is the number I needed in my case(even though it is wrong) and I hope to achieve it with c++ code without opencv...  Is there any other possible solutions to my problem?? Thx!